# SOS! Hundreds of popups - trying to reduce JS code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some cards in Russian. Each card has its own popup attached by clicking a 'details` button in the card. I am trying to reduce the code, so I don't have to create four separate functions for each unique card id.

At the moment I have 50 such popups, here is a sample of a few of them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*  Третья новость  */
  $('#reg-four').click(function() {
    $('#popup-fade4').fadeIn();
    return false;
  });

  // Клик по ссылке "Закрыть".
  $('#popup__close_four').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('#popup-fade4').fadeOut();
    return false;
  });

  // Закрытие по клавише Esc.
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#popup-fade4').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  // Клик по фону, но не по окну.
  $('#popup-fade4').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#popup4').length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });

  /*  Третья новость  */
  $('#reg-five').click(function() {
    $('#popup-fade5').fadeIn();
    return false;
  });

  // Клик по ссылке "Закрыть".
  $('#popup__close_five').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('#popup-fade5').fadeOut();
    return false;
  });

  // Закрытие по клавише Esc.
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#popup-fade5').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  // Клик по фону, но не по окну.
  $('#popup-fade5').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#popup5').length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });

  /*  Третья новость  */
  $('#reg-six').click(function() {
    $('#popup-fade6').fadeIn();
    return false;
  });

  // Клик по ссылке "Закрыть".
  $('#popup__close_six').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('#popup-fade6').fadeOut();
    return false;
  });

  // Закрытие по клавише Esc.
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#popup-fade6').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  // Клик по фону, но не по окну.
  $('#popup-fade6').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#popup6').length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
div,
p,
img,
form,
input,
a,
i,
p {
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

input:hover,
input,
input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

button,
button:visited,
button:active {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

span,
span:visited,
span:active {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.clearfix {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.way-desc {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.way-desc__title_block {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}

.way-desc__title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 320px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.way-desc__title:after {
  content: '';
  width: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(11, 59, 167, 0.5);
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.way-desc__photo_block {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 350px;
}

.way-desc__photo_block img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.way-desc__text {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 350px;
}

.way-sec__par {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.7);
  width: 75%;
  margin: 20px 42px;
}

.way-desc__title_block:hover {
  background-color: #0b3ba7;
  height: 350px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.way-desc__title_block:hover h3 {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.way-desc__title_block:hover .way-desc__title:after {
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.5);
  top: 55%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.way-desc__text:hover {
  background-color: #0b3ba7;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 350px;
  display: block;
}

.way-desc__text:hover p {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.popup-fade {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.popup__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 336px;
}

.popup__data {
  margin: 26px 0px 24px 42px;
  color: #fab165;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup__title {
  margin: 48px 0px 24px 42px;
  color: #041741;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  width: 700px;
}

.popup__par {
  margin: 0px 0px 24px 42px;
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.76);
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 96.2%;
}

.popup__icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup__close {
  color: #fab165;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3%;
  right: -2%;
}

.popup__close:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0b3ba7;
}

.popup__icon i.fas {
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.1);
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1%;
  left: -1%;
}

.popup__par i.fas.left {
  left: 90%;
  top: 83%;
  position: absolute;
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.1);
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ПЖ.РФ - Путеводитель</title>

  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,800;1,200;1,400;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


</head>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Четвёртый путеводитель -->
  <div class="popup-fade" id="popup-fade4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="popup" id="popup4">
            <div class="popup__img popup__img4"></div>
            <div class="popup__block">
              <a href="" class="popup__close" id="popup__close_four"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              <h3 class="popup__title">ДАЧА СТАЛИНА</h3>
              <p class="popup__par clearfix">
                <span class="popup__icon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>
                                                <i>Хоста, пр. Курортный 120, тел. 8 (862) 297-05-02</i>
                                                Хотите попасть в прошлое, не прибегая к услугам машины времени? Тогда отправляйтесь на дачу Сталина, в одну из 18-ти резиденций великого вождя. Здесь всё осталось таким же, как при жизни советского лидера – «сталинские» интерьеры из ценных пород дерева, зелёный красивый парк и вид на море, вода в котором с этой точки обзора кажется особенно лазурной. 

                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right left"></i>
                                        </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Четвёртый путеводитель -->
  <div class="popup-fade" id="popup-fade5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="popup" id="popup5">
            <div class="popup__img popup__img5"></div>
            <div class="popup__block">
              <a href="" class="popup__close" id="popup__close_five"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              <h3 class="popup__title">ЧАЙНЫЕ ДОМИКИ</h3>
              <p class="popup__par clearfix">
                <span class="popup__icon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>
                                                <i>Уч-Дере, ул. Запорожская 302, тел. 8 (862) 235-16-16</i>
                                                Сочи считается самой северной точкой в мире, где благополучно растёт чай. Сочинский чай почему-то называется «Краснодарским», но его вкусовые качества сродни лучшим индийским и китайским сортам. Убедиться в этом в окружении русских народных интерьеров с самоварами и расписными стенами, наслаждаясь панорамным видом на побережье, можно в знаменитых чайных домиках. 
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right left"></i>
                                        </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Четвёртый путеводитель -->
  <div class="popup-fade" id="popup-fade6">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="popup" id="popup6">
            <div class="popup__img popup__img6"></div>
            <div class="popup__block">
              <a href="" class="popup__close" id="popup__close_six"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              <h3 class="popup__title">33 ВОДОПАДА</h3>
              <p class="popup__par clearfix">
                <span class="popup__icon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>
                                                <i>Головинка, урочище Джегош, в долине реки Шахе, в 4 км севернее п. Большой Кичмай</i>
                                                Каскадное чудо природы на территории Национального парка. Сюда не так-то просто добраться! Неглубокую, но стремительную реку Шахе лучше проехать на сочинском «джипе» или ГАЗ-63, которые регулярно там курсируют. 15 минут экстремальной езды от Большого Кичмая – и вот вас встречают первые высокие водопады. Поднимайтесь дальше, смотрите, купайтесь, отдыхайте и наслаждайтесь кристально чистым воздухом. 
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right left"></i>
                                        </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Блоки содержания для вкладок -->
  <div class="tabs__content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="way-desc clearfix">
          <div class="way-desc__title_block">
            <h3 class="way-desc__title">Дача Сталина</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="way-desc__photo_block"><img src="../img/way/Дача Сталина.jpg" alt="Фото путеводителя" class="way-desc__photo"></div>
          <div class="way-desc__text">
            <p class="way-sec__par">
              Хотите попасть в прошлое, не прибегая к услугам машины времени? Тогда отправляйтесь на дачу Сталина, в одну из 18-ти резиденций великого вождя. Здесь всё осталось таким же, как при жизни советского лидера – «сталинские» интерьеры из ценных пород дерева,
              зелёный красивый парк и вид на море.

            </p>
            <div class="way-desc__link"><a href="#" id="reg-four">Подробнее</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="way-desc clearfix">
          <div class="way-desc__title_block">
            <h3 class="way-desc__title">Чайные домики</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="way-desc__photo_block"><img src="../img/way/Чайный домик.jpg" alt="Фото путеводителя" class="way-desc__photo"></div>
          <div class="way-desc__text">
            <p class="way-sec__par">
              Сочи считается самой северной точкой в мире, где благополучно растёт чай. Сочинский чай почему-то называется «Краснодарским», но его вкусовые качества сродни лучшим индийским и китайским сортам.
            </p>
            <div class="way-desc__link"><a href="#" id="reg-five">Подробнее</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="way-desc clearfix">
          <div class="way-desc__title_block">
            <h3 class="way-desc__title">33 водопада</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="way-desc__photo_block"><img src="../img/way/33 водопада.jpeg" alt="Фото путеводителя" class="way-desc__photo"></div>
          <div class="way-desc__text">
            <p class="way-sec__par">
              Каскадное чудо природы на территории Национального парка. Сюда не так-то просто добраться! Неглубокую, но стремительную реку Шахе лучше проехать на сочинском «джипе» или ГАЗ-63, которые регулярно там курсируют. 15 минут экстремальной езды от Большого
              Кичмая.

            </p>
            <div class="way-desc__link"><a href="#" id="reg-six">Подробнее</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JS & JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How can this be optimized so as not to produce code"? Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Please have a look at our sister network https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It's hard to figure out what the problem is exactly. Can you only show the relevant part of the code? and clearly state what the issue is and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Ibu I think the OP is trying to reduce the code because they will have several cards that each have a `Details` button and rather than writing JS for each card (`ID`), they want it to be more efficient.

Comment: @Ibu 
The comment above is correct.
They didn’t help me on the Russian resource, I decided to contact me here

Comment: @ИринаСтеценко I updated the description and title for you (cleaned up the English a little bit) so you can get more help.

Answer (score 1):

I cut your JavaScript down to four functions.

You will need to edit your HTML a little bit for this to work. I added a `data-target` to each `.popup-fade` element that matches the `id` of the `a` details link. I commented all the lines in the JS that I changed so you know what I did.

If you can't change your HTML, you probably won't be able to do this easily.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*  Третья новость  */
  // Just use the generic a tag here
  $('.way-desc__link a').click(function() {
    // Get the id of the link
    var link_id = $(this).attr('id');
    /* target the div (.popup-fade) that has the data-target that is the same as the link id */ 
    $('div[data-target="' + link_id + '"]').fadeIn();
    return false;
  });

  // Клик по ссылке "Закрыть".
  /* Use the class here. No need for an id because you are only targeting the parent elements of that specific div. */
  $('.popup__close').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.popup-fade').fadeOut();
    return false;
  });

  // Закрытие по клавише Esc.
  // Use the class .popup-fade instead since it's only the one open. No need to use the ID.
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('.popup-fade').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  // Клик по фону, но не по окну.
  // use the class since the closest .popup will be open. no need to use the ID.
  $('.popup-fade').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.popup').length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
div,
p,
img,
form,
input,
a,
i,
p {
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

input:hover,
input,
input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

button,
button:visited,
button:active {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

span,
span:visited,
span:active {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.clearfix {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.way-desc {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.way-desc__title_block {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}

.way-desc__title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 320px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.way-desc__title:after {
  content: '';
  width: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(11, 59, 167, 0.5);
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.way-desc__photo_block {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 350px;
}

.way-desc__photo_block img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.way-desc__text {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 350px;
}

.way-sec__par {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.7);
  width: 75%;
  margin: 20px 42px;
}

.way-desc__title_block:hover {
  background-color: #0b3ba7;
  height: 350px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.way-desc__title_block:hover h3 {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.way-desc__title_block:hover .way-desc__title:after {
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.5);
  top: 55%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.way-desc__text:hover {
  background-color: #0b3ba7;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  height: 350px;
  display: block;
}

.way-desc__text:hover p {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.popup-fade {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.popup__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 336px;
}

.popup__data {
  margin: 26px 0px 24px 42px;
  color: #fab165;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup__title {
  margin: 48px 0px 24px 42px;
  color: #041741;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  width: 700px;
}

.popup__par {
  margin: 0px 0px 24px 42px;
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.76);
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 96.2%;
}

.popup__icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup__close {
  color: #fab165;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3%;
  right: -2%;
}

.popup__close:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0b3ba7;
}

.popup__icon i.fas {
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.1);
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1%;
  left: -1%;
}

.popup__par i.fas.left {
  left: 90%;
  top: 83%;
  position: absolute;
  color: rgba(4, 23, 65, 0.1);
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ПЖ.РФ - Путеводитель</title>

  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,800;1,200;1,400;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


</head>
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Четвёртый путеводитель -->
  <div class="popup-fade" id="popup-fade4" data-target="reg-four">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="popup" id="popup4">
            <div class="popup__img popup__img4"></div>
            <div class="popup__block">
              <a href="" class="popup__close" id="popup__close_four"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              <h3 class="popup__title">ДАЧА СТАЛИНА</h3>
              <p class="popup__par clearfix">
                <span class="popup__icon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>
                                                <i>Хоста, пр. Курортный 120, тел. 8 (862) 297-05-02</i>
                                                Хотите попасть в прошлое, не прибегая к услугам машины времени? Тогда отправляйтесь на дачу Сталина, в одну из 18-ти резиденций великого вождя. Здесь всё осталось таким же, как при жизни советского лидера – «сталинские» интерьеры из ценных пород дерева, зелёный красивый парк и вид на море, вода в котором с этой точки обзора кажется особенно лазурной. 

                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right left"></i>
                                        </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Четвёртый путеводитель -->
  <div class="popup-fade" id="popup-fade5" data-target="reg-five">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="popup" id="popup5">
            <div class="popup__img popup__img5"></div>
            <div class="popup__block">
              <a href="" class="popup__close" id="popup__close_five"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              <h3 class="popup__title">ЧАЙНЫЕ ДОМИКИ</h3>
              <p class="popup__par clearfix">
                <span class="popup__icon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>
                                                <i>Уч-Дере, ул. Запорожская 302, тел. 8 (862) 235-16-16</i>
                                                Сочи считается самой северной точкой в мире, где благополучно растёт чай. Сочинский чай почему-то называется «Краснодарским», но его вкусовые качества сродни лучшим индийским и китайским сортам. Убедиться в этом в окружении русских народных интерьеров с самоварами и расписными стенами, наслаждаясь панорамным видом на побережье, можно в знаменитых чайных домиках. 
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right left"></i>
                                        </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Четвёртый путеводитель -->
  <div class="popup-fade" id="popup-fade6" data-target="reg-six">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="popup" id="popup6">
            <div class="popup__img popup__img6"></div>
            <div class="popup__block">
              <a href="" class="popup__close" id="popup__close_six"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
              <h3 class="popup__title">33 ВОДОПАДА</h3>
              <p class="popup__par clearfix">
                <span class="popup__icon">
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>
                                                <i>Головинка, урочище Джегош, в долине реки Шахе, в 4 км севернее п. Большой Кичмай</i>
                                                Каскадное чудо природы на территории Национального парка. Сюда не так-то просто добраться! Неглубокую, но стремительную реку Шахе лучше проехать на сочинском «джипе» или ГАЗ-63, которые регулярно там курсируют. 15 минут экстремальной езды от Большого Кичмая – и вот вас встречают первые высокие водопады. Поднимайтесь дальше, смотрите, купайтесь, отдыхайте и наслаждайтесь кристально чистым воздухом. 
                                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right left"></i>
                                        </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Блоки содержания для вкладок -->
  <div class="tabs__content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="way-desc clearfix">
          <div class="way-desc__title_block">
            <h3 class="way-desc__title">Дача Сталина</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="way-desc__photo_block"><img src="../img/way/Дача Сталина.jpg" alt="Фото путеводителя" class="way-desc__photo"></div>
          <div class="way-desc__text">
            <p class="way-sec__par">

              зелёный красивый парк и вид на море.

            </p>
            <div class="way-desc__link"><a href="#" id="reg-four">Подробнее</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="way-desc clearfix">
          <div class="way-desc__title_block">
            <h3 class="way-desc__title">Чайные домики</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="way-desc__photo_block"><img src="../img/way/Чайный домик.jpg" alt="Фото путеводителя" class="way-desc__photo"></div>
          <div class="way-desc__text">
            <p class="way-sec__par">
              Сочи считается самой северной точкой в мире, где благополучно растёт чай. Сочинский чай почему-то называется «Краснодарским», но его вкусовые качества сродни лучшим индийским и китайским сортам.
            </p>
            <div class="way-desc__link"><a href="#" id="reg-five">Подробнее</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="way-desc clearfix">
          <div class="way-desc__title_block">
            <h3 class="way-desc__title">33 водопада</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="way-desc__photo_block"><img src="../img/way/33 водопада.jpeg" alt="Фото путеводителя" class="way-desc__photo"></div>
          <div class="way-desc__text">
            <p class="way-sec__par">
              Каскадное чудо природы на территории Национального парка. Сюда не так-то просто добраться! Неглубокую, но стремительную реку Шахе лучше проехать на сочинском 

            </p>
            <div class="way-desc__link"><a href="#" id="reg-six">Подробнее</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JS & JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```